# Nuxtjs asyncdata doesn't keep data after navigation change

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, asyncdata

I am in `pages/index.vue` and for show news in my page, i use asyncdata method but when i goto an other page and come back to home news data are empty. Should i save data on store? Or have other solution for this?

```
   <template>
      <div>
         {{news.length}}

         <nuxt-link to="/about"> about </nuxt-link>
      </div>
   </template>

   <script>
      async asyncData({$axios}){
        return $axios.post("/news")
           .then(({data : {data : news}}) => {
             return {news};
           })
           .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use .env in nuxt.config like this

```
env: {
    appUrl: "localhost:2323"
}
```

and use env parameters in axios config on nuxt.config like this

```
axios: {
    baseUrl : process.env.appUrl
}
```

asyncData doesn`t work on navigation change, And you must set baseUrl directly hardcode.

Answer (score 2):

Yea, usually we store it in a vuex store. It could look something like this:

```
  async asyncData({$axios, store, error}){
      try {
         let news = (await $axios.post("/news")).data.data.news;
         store.commit("SAVE_NEWS", news);
      catch (err) {
         error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Cannot find })
      }
   },
   computed: {
      news() {
         return this.$store.state.news
      }
   }
```

Comment: Doesn't this have a negative effect on SEO?

Comment: @MortezaNegahi asyncData also have the `error` property. No it does not have a negative effect on SEO.